# How to get data when parse Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When parsing I get this answer:

```
{ 
    data: { 
        type: 'match',
        id: 'ae825686-8a74-4363-a1d1-402d5a4207d5',
        attributes: { 
            createdAt: '2018-11-20T17:06:52Z',
            titleId: 'bluehole-pubg',
            shardId: 'pc-ru',
            tags: null,
            seasonState: 'progress',
            duration: 1823,
            stats: null,
            gameMode: 'squad-fpp'
        },
    },  
    included: [ 
        { 
            type: 'participant',
            id: '0b1b8f78-bb3e-4c0a-9955-9fdf8e33e5b4',
            attributes: [Object] 
        },
        { 
            type: 'participant',
            id: '85e74b88-125b-4529-8c3f-fd76bd43b9aa',
            attributes: [Object] 
        },
        { 
            type: 'roster',
            id: '6db70dce-b056-4bed-8cc4-6521b83bea50',
            attributes: [Object],
            relationships: [Object] 
        },
        { 
            type: 'roster',
            id: 'a35db9ae-e559-4474-b922-784e3221f484',
            attributes: [Object],
            relationships: [Object] 
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get data with  **inculded type:'roster'**, and object contents **attributes, relationships**. How can I do it? I tried extracting array of data `console.log(included [0]);` I get data from **type:'participant'.** Tried so `console.log (included [{type: 'roster', relationship}]);` In response, I get the message **undefined** Please tell me how to get the necessary data.

Comment: Do you only want to extract the elements in the `included`-array that has `type` equals to ´'roster´?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const response = { 
    data: { 
        type: 'match',
        id: 'ae825686-8a74-4363-a1d1-402d5a4207d5',
        attributes: { 
            createdAt: '2018-11-20T17:06:52Z',
            titleId: 'bluehole-pubg',
            shardId: 'pc-ru',
            tags: null,
            seasonState: 'progress',
            duration: 1823,
            stats: null,
            gameMode: 'squad-fpp'
        },
    },  
    included: [ 
        { 
            type: 'participant',
            id: '0b1b8f78-bb3e-4c0a-9955-9fdf8e33e5b4',
            attributes: [Object] 
        },
        { 
            type: 'participant',
            id: '85e74b88-125b-4529-8c3f-fd76bd43b9aa',
            attributes: [Object] 
        },
        { 
            type: 'roster',
            id: '6db70dce-b056-4bed-8cc4-6521b83bea50',
            attributes: [Object],
            relationships: [Object] 
        },
        { 
            type: 'roster',
            id: 'a35db9ae-e559-4474-b922-784e3221f484',
            attributes: [Object],
            relationships: [Object] 
        }
    ]
}

const arrayWithRoster = response.included.filter(item => item.type === 'roster');

console.log(arrayWithRoster);
```

Comment: Well, how do I get the contents of attributes, relationships ?

Comment: `{ type: 'roster',
    id: '7b095048-6923-430a-ace8-5269b3148499',
    attributes: { stats: [Object], won: 'false', shardId: 'pc-ru' },
    relationships: { team: [Object], participants: [Object] } } ]` Here is the content I received after filtering

Comment: in the same way now filter new received data?

Comment: you could do something like `arrayWithRoster.forEach(item => item.relationships)` with your own logic

Answer (score 0):

I would create two arrays and push individually, like this:

```
let json = { 
    data: { 
        type: 'match',
        id: 'ae825686-8a74-4363-a1d1-402d5a4207d5',
        attributes: { 
            createdAt: '2018-11-20T17:06:52Z',
            titleId: 'bluehole-pubg',
            shardId: 'pc-ru',
            tags: null,
            seasonState: 'progress',
            duration: 1823,
            stats: null,
            gameMode: 'squad-fpp'
        },
    },  
    included: [ 
        { 
            type: 'participant',
            id: '0b1b8f78-bb3e-4c0a-9955-9fdf8e33e5b4',
            attributes: [Object] 
        },
        { 
            type: 'participant',
            id: '85e74b88-125b-4529-8c3f-fd76bd43b9aa',
            attributes: [Object] 
        },
        { 
            type: 'roster',
            id: '6db70dce-b056-4bed-8cc4-6521b83bea50',
            attributes: [Object],
            relationships: [Object] 
        },
        { 
            type: 'roster',
            id: 'a35db9ae-e559-4474-b922-784e3221f484',
            attributes: [Object],
            relationships: [Object] 
        }
    ]
}
let attributes = [];
let relationships = [];

let dataIneed = json.included.forEach(element => {
   if(element.type === 'roster'){
    attributes.push(element.attributes);
    relationships.push(element.relationships);
  }
})
```